# Storing Java Objects For Further Use in WebApp That Uses REST

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have a webapp which make REST call for respective functionalities.
Say, I have a webapp in which a user registers and a KeyValue pair is generated which is required for authentication during ssh. 
Now this KeyValue pair is unique.
And the other web page of the same application I want those KeyValue pair to be downloaded as a ppk file to ssh. "So that particular object is required".

So is there a way to store the object.
I do have a Postgres DB.
What are my possible options?
**Edit:** The Object I want to store, is a third-party implemented library JSch (which is an full implementation of SSH-2), so simple Key-Value pair might not be solution I guess!)

Comment: Do any of the answers work for your scenario ?

Comment: I stored it on the server machine and in DB also for future purpose. I got for a simple and straight solution

Comment: Can we discuss your solution

Comment: I uploaded my answer below @Prateek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wanted a key for ssh'ing into my machine which is provided by KeyPair Object of JSch. I did stored it in my database by serializable for future applications like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="keypairs")
public class KeyPairDomain {

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private byte[] byteObject;
    private KeyPair keypair;

    public KeyPairDomain(KeyPair kpair, String username) {
        super();
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.keypair = kpair;
    }

    @Transient
    public KeyPair getKeypair() {
        return keypair;
    }


    public void setKeypair(KeyPair complexObject) {
        this.setKeypair(complexObject);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            out.writeObject(complexObject);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.byteObject = baos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "bytea") 
    public byte[] getByteObject() {
    return byteObject;
    }

    public void setByteObject(byte[] byteObject) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais;
        ObjectInputStream in;
        try {
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteObject);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            setKeypair((KeyPair) in.readObject());
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.byteObject = byteObject;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

but I stored a ppk file in a tmp folder of any machine type. And when required I use that location to fetch that key.

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@POST
@Path("/getCredentials")
public Response getCredentials(HashMap<String, String> userDetails) {

    String username = userDetails.get("username");
    File homedir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    File file = new File(homedir, "credentials/" + username + "/Key.ppk");
    System.out.println("File Path: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File Name: "+file.getName());
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +file.getName()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

REST is stateless so is not possible to mantain it on the server side!

You can create a token that is the encryption of the couple key, value on the server side and send it to the client (browser).

The browser is responsible to mantain the token and send it to the server if needed.

The server can decrypt the token and retrieve the original key value couple.

This will grant you that the client can't access to the couple key value because it is encrypted in a manner that the client can't read it.

---

**Note** If you need to mantain those values only for a limited quantity of time you can encrypt in the token also a value corresponding to the creation of token or to last access to the token.

This technique is generally used to mantain "sessions" on client side in an application that use only REST calls, but needs to maintain informations related to the current user.

Comment: Davide ,The problem that lies here is, if browser is going to maintain the Object then, well I think you are suggesting LocalStorage or SessionStorage, but it can be altered and changed, i.e it is accessible however not readable. So that might not be a good idea for the project IMO.

Comment: It can't be changed because it is encrypted with a private key and a change to that will invalid the token itself.

Comment: That's the issue, if it gets invalid, then it becomes useless when I will require it. Or is there more to it?

Comment: If it gets invalid it means that somebody has tried to change it on the browser manually. So it is a try to violate your server. Is correct to block the access in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, nice point. On other note, is there a server side option, on which the server is deployed, or serialize in a DB, basically if I want to remove the accessiblity to the end user.

Comment: Why you would like to remove the accessibility to the end user to a data that is not readable? It is the equivalent of a session token, like for example the cookie JSESSIONID

Comment: The thing is he can close the machine and logs in to the machine from a different machine as it may be hosted on the web. So, when I will require it, it will not be there. I hope I am making it clear, i.e end user may connect at a different period of time and use that Object that I want to use at further point.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store a single key/value pair, then you can store it in the session. If you want to store multiple pairs, it works similar, but you'd store a *collection* of pairs in the session. Have a look at HttpServletRequest.getSession() for details.

If you want to share the key/value pair across all sessions (other users, multiple browsers) and you only have a single web server, just use a static variable.

If you want to share the key/value pair across all sessions and you have multiple servers, then you'll have to store it in the database (unless you'd consider build some data exchange protocol between servers, but I doubt that would be the simplest thing you could do).

Comment: REST is stateless. It means no session.

Comment: Session is not an option here. But storing to DB seems like an option.

Comment: The session is part of the webapp, not of the REST service that gets called by the webapp. The service being RESTful (and thus stateless) doesn't imply that the webapp is stateless too. Aakash's statement that the session is not an option makes it clear though.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the key value pair in DB. You can use redis for faster access to this pair similar to a cache and auto delete based on expiration time you want to set.

This is the same way data is cached by servers in sessions. Since REST APIs are dateless, you have this alternate which should work just fine.